# How to check for waiting notification messages when application start

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

I implemented Google Cloud Messaging for Android (GCM). I'm using  the GCM service:

```
 <service android:name=".GCMIntentService" />
```

and when new message arrive the onMessage fired:

```
 protected void onMessage(Context context, Intent intent) {
```

i'm only facing one issue if `GCMIntentService` service for some reason stop working, and new notification arrive. Now, even when user launch app, the above `onMessage` don't get fired.

I wonder in this case if there away for app to check if there any new waiting notification, that have be missed because GCMIntentService wasn't running.

the issue is `GCMIntentService` only start to work when user launch app for first time, but consider for example the case when user restart handset, in this case `GCMIntentService` still not running.

Comment: It's not possible to handle from our side, Google handles it..

Comment: But I wonder how other application like "whatsapp" handle this scenario.

Comment: whatsapp does not using GCM infrastructure instead it used XMPP protocol for sending and receiving messages.

Comment: Thanks  ... I think now I undertsand the issue ... but not sure I found the best solution ... see my question @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14479959/best-practice-to-save-incoming-notification-for-later-app-retreival